# How to show Day of Week in Order by Day of Week in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-dates

I have the following formula that displays a total by Day of Week (weekday) from a date in `J` and amount in `K`

Example
`J` contains 1/1/2020 ... until 9/29/2020
`K` contains numeric value 123 ... 1999

```
=Query(ArrayFormula({{unique(text(J2:J,"DDDD"))},
 {sumif(text(J2:J,"DDDD"),
 unique(text(J2:J,"DDDD")),K2:K)}}),"Select * where Col2<0")
```

All the values are correct, they just are not in the order of days, ie
Sunday Monday Tuesday Wednesday ... Saturday

Instead, I have the data showing like this

```
Friday    1,220.00
Monday    1,234.00
Tuesday   1,999.00
Thursday  1,555.00
Saturday  1,666.00
Wednesday 1,777.00
```

What I would want is

```
Monday    1,234.00
Tuesday   1,999.00
Wednesday 1,777.00
Thursday  1,555.00
Friday    1,220.00
Saturday  1,666.00
```

Answer (score 1):

### EDIT 2

*Following OP's 2nd [request](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/146558/how-to-show-day-of-week-in-order-by-day-of-week-in-google-sheets/146562?noredirect=1#comment134143_146562)*

> The same day, as in 1/1/2020, then another 1/1/2020 counts as 2 when it should count as 1.

[image]

### EDIT 1

*Following OP's [request](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/146558/how-to-show-day-of-week-in-order-by-day-of-week-in-google-sheets#comment134112_146562)*

> Could the formula show a column that counts How many Sundays, How Many Mondays, etc ?

Just add `count(J)` as part of the [`select`](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#select) clause

Please use the updated formula where I also added an exclusion of Sundays and a custom format for the `Totals` column.

```
=Query(J2:K, "select dayOfWeek(J), count(J), sum(K) 
              where J is not null and dayOfWeek(J)<>1
              group by dayOfWeek(J) 
              order by  dayOfWeek(J) 
              label dayOfWeek(J) 'Day', sum(K) 'Totals', count(J) '# of days' 
              format dayOfWeek(J) 'dddd', sum(K) '$#,##0.00' ")
```

*(Compare the two and notice the different results)*

---

**Original answer**

Instead of using your formula you can also use the following query

```
=Query(J2:K, "select dayOfWeek(J), sum(K) 
              where J is not null 
              group by dayOfWeek(J) 
              order by  dayOfWeek(J) 
              label dayOfWeek(J) 'Day', sum(K) 'Totals' 
              format dayOfWeek(J) 'dddd' ")
```

[image]

Functions used:

- [`QUERY`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343)

Comment: Could the formula show a column that counts How many Sundays, How Many Mondays, etc ?

Comment: *"Could the formula show a column that counts How many Sundays, How Many Mondays, etc ?"*. **No problem**. Please check the updated answer.

Comment: That does not work as Count(J) now counts the number of multiple rows on same Monday, same Tuesday. The needed count is number of unique Mondays, Tuesdays

Comment: Perhaps the issue is also that days are formatted (my error) as 01/01/20 .. 09/29/20

Comment: Sorry, I do not quite understand what you mean. Please read how to and [share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/117311) so as you can be easier helped.

Comment: The same day, as in 1/1/2020, then another 1/1/2020 counts as 2 when it should count as 1. I am not counting how many transactions/rows for 1/1/2020, but want to know how many weekdays represent all of the 1/1/2020 rows.

Comment: Example of using today with 2 rows should result in Wednesday 1 333                                  https://postimg.cc/pyz5hxkJ

Comment: The Count of Days should show 1 Tuesday and 1 Wednesday but it shows number of rows for these days.   https://i.postimg.cc/nzfXm1Cy/2020-10-07-08-05-39.jpg

Comment: Finally we arrived. :) Please check my once more edited answer. **For future reference**: comments should be used for clarifications on the original question. Please do post a new question when the original is  altered through comments. Otherwise it gets confusing to users.

Comment: Allow me one last time to also ask, can I also show that same data but sorted by name of Month, like =QUERY(Query(J2:K, "select (J), sum(K) 
                    where J is not null 
                    group by (J) 
                    order by  month(J) "),
              "select month(Col1), Count(Col1), Sum(Col2)
               group by month(Col1) 
               label month(Col1) 'Month', sum(Col2) 'Total', count(Col1) '#' 
               format month(Col1) 'mmmm', sum(Col2) '###0.' ")

Comment: I am sorry but I lost interest in your requests and the way you appreciated my response to them *(though you accepted the original answer you later and after answering your comment requests you decided to un-accept it)*. Furthermore, please refer to my previous comment about how comments work.

Comment: I followed the directions given to me on this forum and opened a new, separate question. Upon opening it, I was admonished to NOT to open a new question but to close it and come back to this original related question, re-open it and add question. So, I followed the instructions given.

Comment: *"I followed the directions given to me on this forum..."*. Clearly you were misled. :( Even so, un-accepting a correct answer serves no-one.